# How to use index in ListView using Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, listview, nativescript

I have a question about my code:

I used ListView in my project, code like below:

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="countries" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"
    style="height:1250px">
    <ng-template let-country="item" let-i="index">
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
            <Label [text]="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%"></Label>
            <Label [text]="country.price" class="list-group-item-heading"
                verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%"></Label>
            <Button (tap)="decrementQty($event)" text='-' style="width: 60%">
            </Button>
            <TextField row="1" col="1" class="textfield" [text]="qty"
                editable="false" style="width: 60%">
            </TextField>
            <Button (tap)="incrementQty($event)" text='+' style="width: 60%">
            </Button>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

[Demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rVJyY4)

My question is: How to use index? So when I click button `(tap)="incrementQty($event)"` I want to increment Qty only in one row, not in all rows. For this I declare in ng-table index, but not function. Can you suggest me any solution please?

Comment: Do you want to increment a single item in countries list?

Comment: Yes, increment a single item, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rVJyY4&v=2). You have defined the qty at page level, that is why when you were incrementing or decremnting the qty , it was getting applied to all rows.
If you want to play with qty in each row, it should be part of dataprovider e.g.

```
countries: { name: string, product_id: string, price: number, qty: number }[] = [
        { name: "Australia", product_id: "1", price: 100, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Belgium", product_id: "2", price: 1009, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Bulgaria", product_id: "3", price: 1008, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Canada", product_id: "4", price: 1006, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Switzerland", product_id: "5", price: 1000, qty: 1 },
        { name: "China", product_id: "6", price: 1011, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Czech Republic", product_id: "7", price: 150, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Germany", product_id: "8", price: 109, qty: 1 },
        { name: "Spain", product_id: "9", price: 10, qty: 16 },
        { name: "Ethiopia", product_id: "10", price: 105, qty: 1 }
    ];
```

and on increment so omething like this

```
incrementQty(args: ItemEventData, i) {
        console.log(i);
        // console.log(this.countries[i].qty + 1);
        this.countries[i].qty += 1;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to add new property in my JSON file, because JSON file I get form backend. Thank you!

Comment: It’s fine even you are getting json from backend, you can add id before aasiging it to list.

Comment: I use `(tap)="incrementQty(country.product_id)"` but how to use it in function? I can't understand

Comment: incrementQty(product_id) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.countries.length; i++) {
            if (this.countries[i].product_id == product_id) {
                this.countries[i].qty += 1;
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<Button (tap)="incrementQty($event, i)" text='+' style="width: 60%">
</Button>
```

And in js use the following

```
function incrementQty($event, i) {
   this.countries[i].qty++;
}
```

Comment: It should work try to use a debugger to see what goes inside incrementQty function on button click

Comment: @AlonBi Simply pointing it doesn't work won't help any one. If you are facing issues, then share the updated Playground sample to show how you applied this in your code.

Comment: New demo https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XkSQ2Z with change code

Comment: Also, I don't want to add new property in my JSON file, because JSON file I get form backend. Thank you!